# How to properly use testing tool.py with a cpp file?

Tags: python, c++, windows, cmd

I am currently practising google kickstart and I want to test my code using their testing_tool.py. Using cmder to open the testing_tool.py gives me instruction on how to use the tool, but it gives 
**Failed to start running your code. Error:
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified**. I already made sure that the file location is correct. Here a screenshots of the terminal:
[image]

Comment: You must pass the binary, not the code

Comment: @RoQuOTriX how do i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

`./` is the prefix for "this folder", which means you are trying to tell it to look for `D:` in the folder you are in.

Comment: by "this folder" i am currently at the folder where tetsting_tool.py in ?